# Kubernetes cron job running 1 minutes earlier

Tags: linux, kubernetes, timezone, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I have kubernetes cluster which has installed on "EST" time zone, if i see the job describe which say ran at "**Sun, 02 Feb 2020 19:01:09 -0500**" and my cron expression says schedule: **"1 0 * * *"  "** ie every day at 12:01 minutes and i see below Job also started at the same time but in EST time zone

```
Parallelism:              1
Completions:              1
Start Time:               Sun, 02 Feb 2020 19:01:09 -0500
Completed At:             Sun, 02 Feb 2020 19:01:24 -0500
Duration:                 15s
Active Deadline Seconds:  30s
Pods Statuses:            0 Running / 1 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

But when i see the logs of Pod ie showing its ran 1 minutes prior to the schedule

```
 2020-02-02 23:59:51,154 INFO TestMetrics - Daily Job : TestMetrics  Daily Job Script Started - V1.0.0
```

I want below clarification?

1. Is POD always run in UTC Timezone? if Master and worker node Timezone is configured as EST
2. Why Job ran  1 minutes earlier then the Scheduled?

Linux version :

```
3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
```

Kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:39:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.12", GitCommit:"a8b52209ee172232b6db7a6e0ce2adc77458829f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T12:04:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is POD always run in UTC Timezone? if Master and worker node Timezone is configured as EST

All CronJob `schedule:` times are based on the timezone of the master where the job is initiated. More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

> 2. Why Job ran 1 minutes earlier then the Scheduled?

The cron expression that you have showed us is wrong. It should be:

- `0 1 12 ? * * *` if the job should trigger 1 min after midday, or
- `0 1 0 ? * * *` if the job should trigger 1 min after midnight

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for comment , the issue is with POD always runs with UTC Timezone its not as master node timezone , i have raised the github issue for the same https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/19003

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Document is updated for this 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/